# Factory data reset and how to back it normal

Tags: android, iphone

When you press a factory data reset how will.you. Turn back it in original and restore a all data apps because the all data is delete or uninstal how could.be back.it

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 methods to recover data after factory reset**

1. Using backup - Recover data after factory reset with backup.

   If you have a good habit to do a regular backup with cloud service like Google, it would comparatively easy to recover files after factory reset Android phone.

   - Factory reset data recovery with Google-account

     An option during the setup process will allow you to restore all the synced data.

   [image]

   - You can recover data after factory reset via local-backup

     If you have backed up data regularly, then, after a factory reset, just go to “Settings” > “Back up & restore”, and select the latest backup file to restore data from backup.
     [image]
2. Recover Data after factory reset Android without Backup by using [Gihosoft Free Android Data Recovery](https://www.gihosoft.com/android-data-recovery-free.html)